# How to get a more specific "why" of the error?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

In my Node backend, I am using Express-validator to do some request body checks. For some reason if I include the code to check one of the form values, it will always give me an error "Invalid Value" (the default error message).

My question is: Is there any way to get more specifics about the error? From what I know about it, all I can get is which one it is throwing the error on, what the value is, and what the error is. But I can't find *why* the value is invalid... and I can't really fix it, if I don't know why.

What should I do? I have looked at the API documentation for express-validator, but haven't found anything that might help.

Comment: Can you use [`.withMessage`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#withmessagemessage)?

Comment: That is just to customize the message when there is an error. Without this, by default `express-validator` sends the "Invalid Value" message, which is what I get. I want to know _why_ I am getting that error message.

Comment: If you put a `.withMessage` after every individual check, you can tailor the message to that check. If `.exists` fails, say so. If `.isString` fails, say so. If a more complex condition fails, say so.

Comment: Well, thank you for mentioning that method! I just commented out my custom validator (the only one that I use on that value), and then added a built in one (with that method). I didn't get an error, so I knew it was in my custom validator, and I realized that I didn't return the `[collection].findById()` and so it sends back the error, because nothing else is returned. It now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Heiko Theißen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16462950/heiko-thei%c3%9fen)'s comment, I went to check/test my validation again, and eventually figured out that the problem was my custom validator, I wasn't returning the `[collection].findById()` and so when I return the value in there, it didn't work.

So if you are having this problem, please check custom validators, and add the `.withMessage()` to other validators.

- If you think your custom validators are all correct and you still get the error, comment out your custom validators (and add a built in one if necessary).
- If you still get the error, you now know that it has something to do with your custom validator.